# XAMPP MySQL database problem

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am working on Microsoft Windows 11.
Occasionally (seems random), when I open XAMPP it appears to open an old version of my MySQL database.
When this happens, all new information I entered on a previous occasion disappears, with no obvious way of retrieving it - except from a backup.
It's a pain because I now have to thoroughly check that the database is correct before I start to add new records.
Has anyone experienced this before, or have any ideas how to fix it?
I have purposely tried to recreate the fault but can't. It just happens at random when XAMPP is started.

Comment: it is more probable that you have **two** mysql/nariadb process, that try to start on the same port , and the first one wins, that can differ depending on circumstances. simple change the port of the old version to 33907  in the my.ini file and that will not happen any more

Comment: @nbk, I think you're right. I have noticed that XAMPP opens two instances of the control panel if you accidentally double-click the icon instead of using a single click. I would have thought there would be an option in XAMPP to prevent two instances loading.